# How to query bigquery tables in google data studio with python-like string formatting in table names based on custom parameters?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, looker-studio

So I have several tables with each product for each year and tables go like:
`2020product5, 2019product5, 2018product6` and so on. I have added two custom parameters in google data studio as well named year and product_id but could not use them in table names themselves. I have used parameterized queries before but in conditions like `where product_id = @product_id` but this setup only works if all of the data is in same table which is not the current case with me. In python I use string formatters like `f"{year}product{product_id}"` but that obviously does not work in this case...
Using Bigquery Default [CONCAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions) & [FORMAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions) functions does not help as both throw following validation error: `Table-valued function not found: CONCAT at [1:15]`

**So how do I get around with querying  bigquery tables in google data studio with python-like string formatting in table names based on custom parameters?**

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475252/can-i-use-a-query-parameter-in-a-table-name/51479617

Comment: No this is not. It only covers table suffixes part which is the current work around I am using as I mentioned in my answer below. My question is about dynamically selecting tables which are different from each other. More different than mere suffixes which infact is a single table partitioned by suffixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I (kinda) sorted it out. Turns out it is a database level feature to query schema-level entities e.g. table names dynamically. BigQuery does not support formatting within table name like tables as per in question (e.g. `2020product5`, `2019product5`, `2018product6`) cannot be queried directly. However, it does have a TABLE_SUFFIX function which allow you to access tables dynamically given that changes in table names are located at the end of the table. (This feature also allowed for dateweise partitioning and many tools which use BQ as data sink, utilize this. So If you are using BQ as data sink, there is good chance that your original data source is already doing so). Thus, table names like (`product52020`, `product52019`, `product62018`) as well can be accessed dynamically and of course from data studio too using following:

```
SELECT * FROM `project_salsa_101.dashboards.product*` WHERE _table_Suffix = CONCAT(@product_id,@year)
```

P.S.: Used python to create a dirty script which looped through products and tables and copied and created new ones which goes as follows: (Adding script with formatted string so it might be useful for anyone with such case wtih nominal effort)

```
import itertools
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'project_salsa_101-bq-admin.json')
project_id = 'project_salsa_101'
schema = 'dashboards'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

for product_id, year in in itertools.product(product_ids, years): 
    df = client.query(f"""
            SELECT *  FROM `{project_id}.{schema}.{year}product{product_id}`
            """).result().to_dataframe()
    df.to_gbq(project_id = project_id,
                destination_table = f'{schema}.product{product_id}{year}',
                credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                    'credentials.json'),
                if_exists = 'replace')
    client.query(f"""
            DROP TABLE `{project_id}.{schema}.{year}product{product_id}`""").result()
```